# How would i pass an object to a Javafx class in order to procedurally create the GUI?

Tags: java, oop, javafx

So I've been looking around and couldn't find an answer that matches my question. Apologies if this question has been answered.

Here are my two classes:
Game Class

```
    package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends Application{
    Player Player;
    Map Map;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
        Group root = new Group();
        double x =0;
        double y = 0;
        for (Tile[] out: Map.Tiles_Array) {
            for (Tile in : out) {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                rectangle.setHeight(10);
                rectangle.setWidth(10);
                rectangle.setX(x);
                rectangle.setY(y);
                root.getChildren().add(rectangle);
                x = x + 10;
            }
            y = y+ 10;
            x = 0;
        }



        VBox box = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(box);


        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(null);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public Game(Map map , Player player) {
        Map= map;
        Player = player;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }


    void update(){


    }
}
```

``   MainMenu class

```
   package sample;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Print("***************************************************");
        Print("* Welcome to the best Object Orientated game ever *");
        Print("***************************************************");
        Print("What is your Name?");
        var Name = User_Input();
        Print("Are you Male Or Female (M/F)");
        char Gender = Check_Gender(User_Input().charAt(0));
        Print("Whats is your age");
        int Age = Exception_Catcher();
        Print("Great, Now you need to choose your avatar that you will play with......");
        Print("Your choice is between Archer(A), Knight(K) or Wizard(W)");
        Characters Chosen_Character = Check_Choice(User_Input().charAt(0));

        Print(Name + "   " + Gender +"     "+ Age + "     " + Chosen_Character.Name); // debugging
        Player player1 = new Player(Name,Age,Gender,Chosen_Character);
        var Map = new Map(25,25 , player1);
        Game My_Game = new Game(Map,player1);



    }
    private static void Print(String input){ // Prints string it is given
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    private static String User_Input(){ // returns Users response
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        return s.nextLine();
    }
    private static char Check_Gender(char Letter){
        Letter = Character.toUpperCase(Letter);
        if(Letter == 'M'){return Letter;}
        else if(Letter == 'F'){return Letter;}
        else{
            Print("Choose M or F");
            return Check_Gender(User_Input().charAt(0));
        }
    }
    private static Characters Check_Choice(char Letter){
        Letter = Character.toUpperCase(Letter);
        if(Letter == 'A'){
            return new Archer(50,2,10);
        }
        else if(Letter == ('K')){
            return new Knight(100,1,20);
        }
        else if(Letter ==('W')){
            return new Wizard(25,5,5);
        }
        else{
            Print("Choose one of the correct options:Archer(A), Knight(K) or Wizard(W)");
            return Check_Choice(User_Input().charAt(0));
        }

    }
    private static int Exception_Catcher(){ //exception handling for when the user enters a non numerical value
        try{
             return Check_Age(Integer.parseInt(User_Input()));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Print("That's not a correct number format, try again");
            return Exception_Catcher();
        }
    }
    private static int Check_Age(int Age){

            if (Age <= 0) {
                Print("You are not alive apparently");
                return Exception_Catcher();
            } else if (Age > 120) {
                Print("You are not that old!! stop being silly");
                return Exception_Catcher();
            } else {
                return Age;
            }


    }

}
```

Once my Map object and the Player object gets created, I want to pass it onto Game in order to procedurally create graphics for the game. I tried constructing the Game class to call the method Start however it requires a 'Stage' however when I create a default stage and pass it as an argument it throws multiple exceptions.

Comment: Please post [mre]

Comment: java naming conventions please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start your game from `Application.launch(args)` so consider the following structure :

```
public class Game extends Application{

    private Player player;
    private Map map;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
        player = mm.getPlayer();
        map = mm.getMap();
        //rest of the code remains the same 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`MainMenu` only receives user input and constructs a `Player` and a `Map`:

```
public class MainMenu {

    private String name,age,gender,chosenCharacter;
    private final Player player;
    private final Map map;

    public MainMenu()  {
        getUserInput();
        player = new Player(name,age,gender,chosenCharacter);
        map = new Map(25,25 , player);
    }

    private void getUserInput(){ // returns Users response
        //todo
    }

    Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    Map getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

A better option is to get user input by using GUI:

```
public class GetUserInput {

    private Player player;
    private Map map;
    private final TextField nameTf,  ageTf, genderTf,  characterTf;

     GetUserInput() {

         Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<>();
         dialog.setTitle("Game Setting");
         dialog.setHeaderText("Please enter your prefrences");

         // Set the button types.
         ButtonType buttonType = new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
         dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

         //Add event handler to ok button 
         Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(buttonType);
         okButton.setOnAction(e-> processInput());
         //todo hanlde response when cancel button is pressed 

         // Create labels and fields.
         GridPane grid = new GridPane();
         grid.setHgap(10);
         grid.setVgap(10);
         grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

         nameTf = new TextField();
         nameTf.setPromptText("Name");

         ageTf = new TextField();
         ageTf.setPromptText("Age");

         genderTf = new TextField();
         genderTf.setPromptText("Gender");

         characterTf = new TextField();
         characterTf.setPromptText("Character");
         //todo add validation to all text fields

         grid.add(new Label("Name:"), 0, 0);
         grid.add(nameTf, 1, 0);
         grid.add(new Label("Age:"), 0, 1);
         grid.add(ageTf, 1, 1);
         grid.add(new Label("Gender:"), 0, 2);
         grid.add(genderTf, 1, 2);
         grid.add(new Label("Character:"), 0, 3);
         grid.add(characterTf, 1, 3);

         dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

         // Request focus on the name field
         Platform.runLater(() -> nameTf.requestFocus());
         dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    private void processInput() {
        String name = nameTf.getText();
        String age = ageTf.getText();
        String gender = genderTf.getText();
        String chosenCharacter = characterTf.getText();

        player = new Player(name,age,gender,chosenCharacter);
        map = new Map(25,25 , player);
    }

    Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    Map getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

And use it by:

```
    GetUserInput getUserInput = new GetUserInput();
    player = getUserInput.getPlayer();
    map = getUserInput.getMap();
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember is that your user interface isn't just a random collection of JavaFX components, but includes your code. Therefore you can put your code wherever you wish. Well, sort of.

I would create an object to store much of my state, perhaps calling this Game. Every Event subclass that exists might reference this to decide what the next state of the game should be.

If this is a zork-like game (many rooms, objects to pick up and discard, many exits) I would create an array of Room's, each Room would either be a Room object or a subclass of Room, depending on how difficult the room is. Objects would just be a base "Thing" class, with possible subclasses depending on what the thing was supposed to do. Each Room would describe its exits to the program, which would create the proper buttons. Some rooms would allow the player to do something inside the room ("wash hands in the pool" maybe) and there would be responses for some of them, and generic responses for others ("I don't know how to do that, Dave.").

Most of the buttons would be for exits. The EventHandler for the button would contain information from the Room about which new room to enter.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of a game with this style, however, only the Character creation is text-based via the console. 

Once the information is gathered I was hoping to switch it to a Window where the player has a map and can move to different tiles, each tile would know its coordinates as well as whether it contains items such as Damage potion.

The class Map already contains a 2d array of Tiles which I was hoping to correspond to rectangles that would be drawn.

My only issue is, I'm not sure how to pass that map which I already created so it can be used to create the map.

Comment: Half the fun of the zork-likes was making the map. Being given the map seems like cheating, somehow.

Comment: "the Character creation is text-based via the console". This just doesn't make any sense to me. If you're writing a GUI program, why have any user interaction via a console? Why not just create a UI for that too, and show it before going to the main UI?

Comment: That's true, I think i might have been a bit vague when it came to the 'Map' it's a class which is used to generate the graphics. I was hoping to have enemies also which the player can fight with.

Comment: James_D Its for a project, one part of the specification was to use the console for input and output, so yes, I agree it's stupid but its a way of meeting criteria which was convenient for me at the time.

Comment: It’s not really true that you can execute any code you like anywhere in a GUI app. `Scanner.nextLine()` is a blocking call, so you must not execute it on the JavaFX application thread. So to do this in the middle of your GUI code, you’ll need to launch a separate thread, and figure out how to synchronize the data between the multiple threads.